# Unit testing events emitted from stencilJS components in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, stenciljs

I have a angular component, inside the template I have a stencilJS component which is emitting an event which I'm handling in the parent component. I'm trying to write unit-test cases for the "`handleEvent`" method but I couldn't get the component instance of the component by using `By.directive(platformNavbarComponent)`, `spyOn().and.callFake(...)` also did not work or could find any information relating to my problem.

Parent.component.html

```
<cel-platform-navbar 
 (platformSelected)="handleEvent($event)">
</cel-platform-navbar>
```

Parent.component.ts

```
handleEvent(ev) {
 console.log(ev)
}
```

this is the test case I have written and I'm getting the following error

> Expected spy handleEvent to have been called

this is the test case

```
fit('should call handler for "platformSelected" event', () => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('platformSelected', {detail:{navigationUrl: 'abc'}});
    
    fixture.detectChanges();
        
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'handleEvent').and.callThrough();
        
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
    fixture.detectChanges();
        
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
       
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `triggerEventHandler`.

```
fit('should call handler for "platformSelected" event', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'handleEvent').and.callThrough();
    const celPlatformNavbar = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('cel-platform-navbar'));
    celPlatformNavbar.triggerEventHandler('platformSelected', { detail:{navigationUrl: 'abc' }});
    
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
       
  });
```

A good article with a little bit on `triggerEventHandler` [link here](https://netbasal.com/simulating-events-in-angular-unit-tests-5482618cd6c6).

Comment: Thanks.! I was able to get the component instance from "By.css('cel-platform-navbar')'. I misunderstood the usage of By.css()